# May i be the lenght of the square ABCD, where i is the imaginary unit

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers

I know it sounds kinda impossible or very foolish, but if i have a square with side AB = i.  Can i still use the properties from euclidian geometry ?

Comment: I think this is a very interesting and clever question. Just because it is worded poorly doesn't make it bad.

Answer (score 1):

Your question needs more detail.
Before you can ask such a question you have to define the fundamental properties of your space.

In euclidian space e.g. all distances between two points can be described by positive real numbers which have a **total order**. But you wan't to use complex numbers which have no such total order.

You need to understand **how you want to compare distances**.

With total order I mean:

> Given $a, b, c \in \mathbb{R}$:
>
> - $a\geq b \quad \wedge \quad b \geq c \quad \Rightarrow \quad a \geq c$
> - eighter $a \geq b$ or $b \geq a$
> - $a \geq b \quad \wedge \quad a \leq b \quad \Rightarrow \quad a = b$

Comment: What do you mean by total order ?

Comment: But modulus isnt a way of comparing?